# Jqgrid - editrow- getcell

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, jqgrid-asp.net

I have implemented form editing in jqgrid. But after I receive response from server in aftersubmit event, I want to update some cell value in some other row other than the editing row. From jqgrid documentation I understand that we should not use getcell and getrowdata. Without these methods how can I get cell value from other rows within afterSubmit

Answer (score 0):

If you edit a record with id=1 by example, then you can use theses methods **getcell and getrowdata** on record with id = 2.

The limitation apply only on the current editing record.